# RabbitMQ C# message based listener

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to webapplication and in the backend I open a new thread and start a listener.What I want ,open connection one time and rabbitmq listener start and when new message is coming ,it is processed in background.
What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to listen events in web application?

Instead of it, write a windows service using topshelf and masstransit as a rabbitmq client.

You can connect to rabbitmq and register listener consumers in Program.cs as below:

```
IBusControl busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            IRabbitMqHost host = cfg.Host(new Uri(RabbitMQConstants.RabbitMQUri),
                hst =>
                {
                    hst.Username(RabbitMQConstants.RabbitMQUserName);
                    hst.Password(RabbitMQConstants.RabbitMQPassword);
                });

            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host,
                RabbitMQConstants.YourQueueName,
                endPointConfigurator => { endPointConfigurator.Consumer<SomeConsumer>(); });
        });
```

And start bus configurator :

```
        busControl.Start();
```

Example consumer:

```
public class SomeConsumer :
    IConsumer<YourMessageClass>
{
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<YourMessageClass> context)
    {
        await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Message consumed: {context.Message.YourValue}");

    }
}
```

For more information and example take a look at offical masstransit documentation : http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/message-consumers.html

Comment: I cant use windows service ,but it is another issue,what is the best way to do listener ,Subscription or EventingBasicConsumer ?what you suggest

Comment: You can write those above to Startup.cs in your  web api project. I currently test it and queue is declared and consumer binded to it.